# how to compare int and array?

Tags: arrays, int

Im a programming student, I need help with comparing int and array.

```
idNumber =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ID number:"));  
    for (i = 0; (i < student.length) && (idNumber == student[i]); i++)         {  
            choiceIsGood = true;
```

I have declared:
int idNumber;
final int[] student = { 2064009, 2062895, 2063427 };

I want to validate the entry if it is registered in my array.
how will I compare this and proceed with boolean = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. idNumber =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ID number:")); 
2. bool choiceIsGood = false; 
3. for (i = 0; (i < student.length); i++)
4. {
5.    if(idNumber == student[i])  // student[i] is an int, idNumber too !
6.    { // if idNumber == 2064009 or 2062895 or 2063427
7.        choiceIsGood = true; // no need to continue to loop over your array
8.    }
9. }
10.if(choiceIsGood)
11.{
12.  // Do some stuff
13.}
```

Few explanations:

Line: 1. Get User input
Line 2. Declare var outside of the validation system
Line 3. Go through every items of your array
Line 5. check if the user input is the current element of the array
Line 7. Assign true to `choiceIsGood`
Line 10. Check if we passed on `choiceIsGood = true` line.

You never compare two objects which are not of the same type; but the content of an array which has the same type as your input.